# GetString(IStringLocalizer, String, Object[]) returns null when Unit-Testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, localization, moq, .net-core-2.1

I have a test Class that at some point Localizes a String with using the
`GetString(IStringLocalizer, String, Object[])` Extension-Method

The follwing will work except for testing

```
public class ClassToTest
{
    private readonly IStringLocalizer<SharedResource> _localizer;
    
    public AnalyticsLogic(IStringLocalizer<SharedResource> localizer)
    {
        _localizer = localizer;
    }
    
    public async Task<string> SomeMethod()
    {
        return _localizer.GetString("key", DateTime.Today));  // "My Date: 31.10.2018" - will return null when testing
    }       

    public async Task<string> SomeMethod2()
    {
        return _localizer.GetString("key");  // "My Date: {0:d}"
    }
}
```

This is how i built up my test:

```
public class ClassToTestTest
{
    private readonly ClassToTest _testee;
    private readonly Mock<IStringLocalizer<SharedResource>> _localizerMock = new Mock<IStringLocalizer<SharedResource>>();

    public ClassToTestTest()
    {
        _testee = new ClassToTest(_localizerMock.Object);

        _localizerMock.Setup(lm => lm["key"]).Returns(new LocalizedString("key", "My Date: {0:d}"));
    }



    [Fact]
    public async Task SomeMethod()
    {
        var result = await _testee.SomeMethod();

        Assert.Equal($"My Date: {new DateTime(2018, 10, 31):d}", result);
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task SomeMethod2()
    {
        var result = await _testee.SomeMethod2();

        Assert.Equal("My Date: {0:d}", result);
    }
}
```

Running the Test will fail with the following error:

> SomeMethod() failed
>
> - Assert.Equal() Failure
> - Expected: My Date: 31.10.2018
> - Actual:   (null)

Usually I would simply assume the Method `GetString(IStringLocalizer, String, Object[])` not to be able to handle format strings, but since im using this in a productive environment and it works, I have no clue how this may be fixed.  To me it seems like I have properly mocked the `_localizer` dependency. Otherwise  the `GetString(IStringLocalizer, String)` would not return the format-string.

#### Edit:

For clarification:

- Test `SomeMethod()` will fail
- Test `SomeMethod2()` will succeed

Comment: if the mock returns null it usually means that the mock did not get what was expected when invoked.

Comment: @Nkosi its not the mock that returns null, its the extension-Method `GetString(IStringLocalizer, String, Object[])` used in `SomeMethod()` that will not work. The extension-Method `GetString(IStringLocalizer, String)` as used in `SomeMethod2()` works just fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the code for the `GetString` extension methods, the version that takes just a string [does use the method you have mocked](https://github.com/aspnet/Localization/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Localization.Abstractions/StringLocalizerExtensions.cs#L31) but the version that [takes extra parameters doesn't](https://github.com/aspnet/Localization/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Localization.Abstractions/StringLocalizerExtensions.cs#L56):

```
return stringLocalizer[name, arguments];
```

So you need to be mocking this [additional method](https://github.com/aspnet/Localization/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Localization.Abstractions/IStringLocalizer.cs#L27) of [`IStringLocalizer`](https://github.com/aspnet/Localization/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Localization.Abstractions/IStringLocalizer.cs):

```
LocalizedString this[string name, params object[] arguments] { get; }
```

Which I am guessing is something like this:

```
_localizerMock.Setup(lm => lm["key", It.IsAny<object[]>()])
    .Returns(new LocalizedString("key", "My Date: {0:d}"));
```

Comment: This is it right here. I was just looking for the source. Good work.

Comment: @Nkosi Gotta love open source!

Comment: Of course this looses the possibility to check for the value that has been interpolated into the string, as i twill return `My Date: {0:d}` but it works. Thanks a lot.